# Accessing the executing thread's private variables within a task in OpenMP

Tags: c, task, openmp

I am trying to learn OpenMP, and have stumbled upon the fact that threads do not retain their own data when executing tasks, but they rather have a copy of the data of the thread which has generated the task.  Let me demonstrate it with an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp single
        {
            printf("Thread ID of the #single: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
#pragma omp task
                {
                    sleep(1);
                    printf("thread_id, ID of the executing thread: %d, %d\n", thread_id, omp_get_thread_num());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

An example output of this code is as follows:

```
Thread ID of the #single: 1
thread_id, ID of the executing thread: 1, 2
thread_id, ID of the executing thread: 1, 0
thread_id, ID of the executing thread: 1, 3
thread_id, ID of the executing thread: 1, 1
...
```

It is evident that the `thread_id` within the task refers to a copy that is assigned to the `thread_id` of the thread that has created the task (i.e. the one running the *single* portion of the code).

What if I wanted to refer the executing thread's own private variables then? Are they unrecoverably shadowed? Is there a clause to make this code output `number, same number` instead at the end of each line?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to learn OpenMP, and have stumbled upon the fact that
>   threads do not retain their own data when executing tasks, but they
>   rather have a copy of the data of the thread which has generated the
>   task.

"[T]hreads do not retain their own data" is an odd way to describe it.  Attributing data ownership to threads themselves instead of to the tasks they are performing is perhaps the key conceptual problem here.  It is absolutely natural and to be expected that a thread performing a given task operates with and on the data environment *of that task*.

But if you're not accustomed to explicit tasks, then it is understandable that you've gotten away so far without appreciating the distinction here.  The (many) constructs that give rise to implicit tasks are generally structured in ways that are not amenable to detecting the difference.

So with your example, yes,

> the `thread_id` within the task refers to a copy that
>   is assigned to the `thread_id` of the thread that has created the task
>   (i.e. the one running the single portion of the code).

Although it may not be immediately obvious, that follows from the OMP specification:

> When a thread encounters a task construct, an explicit task is
>   generated from the code for the associated structured-block. **The data
>   environment of the task is created according to the data-sharing
>   attribute clauses on the task construct, per-data environment ICVs,
>   and any defaults that apply**.

([OMP 5.0 Specification, section 2.10.1](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu46.html#x70-2000002.10.1); emphasis added)

The only way that can be satisfied is if the task closes over any shared data from the context of its declaration, which is indeed what you observe.  Moreover, this is typically what one wants -- the data on which a task is to operate *should* be established at the point of and by the context of its declaration, else how would one direct what a task is to do?

> What if I wanted to refer the executing thread's own private variables
>   then?

*Threads* do not have variables, at least not in the terminology of OMP.  Those belong to the "data environment" of whatever tasks they are executing at any given time.

> Are they unrecoverably shadowed?

When a thread is executing a given task, it accesses the data environment of that task.  That environment may include variables that are shared with other tasks, but only in that sense can it access the variables of another task.  "Unrecoverably shadowed" is not the wording I would use to describe the situation, but it gets the idea across.

> Is there a clause to make this
>   code output number, same number instead at the end of each line?

There are ways to restructure the code to achieve that, but none of them are as simple as just adding a clause to the `omp task` directive.  In fact, I don't think any of them involve explicit tasks at all.  The most natural way to get that would be with a parallel loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void) {
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

        sleep(1);
        printf("thread_id, ID of the executing thread: %d, %d\n", thread_id, omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, that also simplifies it to the point where it seems trivial, but perhaps that helps drive home the point.  A large part of the purpose of declaring an explicit task is that that task may be executed by a different thread than the one that created it, which is exactly what you need to avoid to achieve the behavior you are asking for.

Comment: I see. Threads do not have any data store belonging to them, then. All data belongs to a task, and some data belong to none (i.e. are shared). I am not exactly sure if it would actually be useful to have data belonging to threads in OMP; it can sure be simulated by having a global array of data-store with thread IDs as indices, to which the threads access with their own ID (queried via the function call). However, I think it would have been interesting, and even less confusing, if OMP did have such a thing. The parallel loop is, I think, something else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that here you create four parallel threads:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
```

and here, you restrict the further execution to one single thread

```
#pragma omp single
    {
        printf("Thread ID of the #single: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
```

From now on, only the context of this single thread is used, hence the same instance of the variable `thread_id` is used. Here

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
#pragma omp task
            {
                sleep(1);
                printf("thread_id, ID of the executing thread: %d, %d\n", thread_id, omp_get_thread_num());
            }
```

you indeed distribute the loop iteration on four threads, but *based on the state of the single task (together with the corresponding instance of `thread_id`* to which you restricted execution above. So a first measure is to end the *single* section directly after the *printf* (before the loop iterations start):

```
    int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp single
    {
        printf("Thread ID of the #single: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    // Now outside the "single"
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ...
```

Now, for each iteration in the for loop, a task is created *immediately*. And this is performed for each of the four threads. So, you now have 40 tasks pending with

- 10 x `thread_id == 0`
- 10 x `thread_id == 1`
- 10 x `thread_id == 2`
- 10 x `thread_id == 3`

These tasks are now distributed amongst the threads arbitrarily. This is where the association between `thread_id` and the *omp thread number* gets lost. There is not much you can do about it, except for removing the

```
#pragma omp task
```

which leads to a similar result (with corresponding omp thread id and `thread_id` numbers), but works a bit different internally (the dissociation of the tasks and the omp threads does not take place).

Comment: No! Only 10 are created because of the loop is in a `single` section. Moreover, removing the `#pragma omp task` do *not* "leads to a similar result" because the 10 tasks are *distributed* between threads and could be executed in parallel by the four threads. Finally, the loop iterations are not distributed on four "tasks" but rather four "threads".

Comment: @JérômeRichard The "40 tasks" relates to the situation when the _single_ section is ended after the `printf()`. The rest depends on your defintion of "similar"; yes, the order may differ. But also here, 4 iterations are executed in parallel now. The typo "tasks" when "threads" were meant is fixed, thank you.

Comment: Ok, it is probably more clear to also put the surrounding context of the last code containing the `#pragma omp single`. Moreover, please note that the parenthesis starting at "(together" is not closed.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Agreed, I have made this more clear now

Comment: The solution offered is completely different in semantics to what I was looking for. The structure I am using in the question distributes 10 tasks to 4 threads, assigning tasks to threads whenever they get free. On yours, each thread separately performs 10 of those tasks, which isn't even parallelizing anything, merely running the exact same thing 4 times on 4 different threads. What would be the purpose of it, anyway?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Since you did not state what you are exactly doing, how should I know? The answer tries to explain to you why the `thread_id` and `omp_thread_num()` does not match and indeed will never match this way, and not to provide a solution to a problem, that you do not even state.

Comment: @Ctx The code I have provided has some parallel semantics in an of itself; it creates 10 tasks, and those 10 tasks are handled by 4 threads. I appreciate that you have answered the question "can a thread executing a task retain its own private variables, if the said task is created by another thread", albeit negatively. However, anything following that is truly off the mark; there, the `thread_id` are equal to `omp_thread_num()` only because the executors and creators of the tasks are the same, not because it solves the problem I definitely have mentioned in the question.